# How to load csv data which is control+A separated into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load a CSV file which is control+A separated into bigquery. What should be the option I pass for `-F` parameter for the bq load command? All the options I have tried are resulting in an error while loading.

Comment: What are the parameters you have tried, and what errors do they give?

Comment: I never heard of control+a separator. You maybe want to regenerate the file with a different separator. Control+a usually stands for select everything.

Comment: Have tried \u0001, \x01, they are failing with "Field delimiter must be a single character" error.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that Control+A is used in some legacy formats that OP wants to load into BigQuery. From the other hand Control+A can be chosen when it is hard to select any of usually used delimiters.

My recommendation would be to load your CSV file without any delimiter, so whole row will be loaded as a one field

Assuming your rows loaded into TempTable look like below with just one column called FullRow.

```
 'value1^Avalue2^Avalue3'
```

where ^A is "invisible" character

So, after you loaded your file into BigQuery - now you can parse it to separate columns and write it to final table with something like below

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(FullRow, r'(?:\w*\x01){0}(\w*)') AS col1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(FullRow, r'(?:\w*\x01){1}(\w*)') AS col2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(FullRow, r'(?:\w*\x01){2}(\w*)') AS col3
FROM TempTable
```

Above is confirmed to work as I used this approach multiple times. Works for both Legacy and Standard SQL

Comment: @amareshwari - did you have chance to try above approach?

Comment: how do you load the file without a delimiter? Just define a custom delimiter: bq load --field_delimiter SomeStringThatDoesNotExistInMyFile?